Unit test with NestJS, Jest and GraphQL : import module fail
I'm new to TDD and Jest, and trying to test the CRUD routes for my app created with NestJS.
The tricky part is that I use GraphQL and could not find any help online that works, at least for me.
I have created the User module with nest g resource users, here is the UserModule :
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersResolver } from './users.resolver';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  providers: [UsersResolver, UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}

users.resolver.spec.ts :
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { UsersResolver } from './users.resolver';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

describe('UsersResolver', () => {
  let resolver: UsersResolver;
  let service: UsersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UsersResolver, UsersService],
    }).compile();

    resolver = module.get<UsersResolver>(UsersResolver);
    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(resolver).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('findAll', () =>
    it("doit retourner un tableau d'utilisateurs", async () => {
      const result: User[] = [
        {
          id: 1,
          firstName: 'User1',
          lastName: 'Name1',
          password: 'azertyuiop',
          email: 'user1@test.com',
          lastConnected: new Date('2024-07-12'),
          createdAt: new Date('2024-07-12'),
          updatedAt: new Date('2024-07-12'),
        },
      ];
      jest.spyOn(service, 'findAll').mockImplementation(async () => result);

      expect(await resolver.findAll()).toBe(result);
    }));
});

With yarn test (provided by NestJS and Jest), tests are started, and my test for the user fail :
PASS  src/auth/auth.service.spec.ts (8.955 s)
 PASS  src/auth/auth.controller.spec.ts (9.065 s)
 PASS  src/app.controller.spec.ts (9.11 s)
 FAIL  src/users/users.service.spec.ts (11.132 s)
  ● UsersService › should be defined

    Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument "UserRepository" at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - Is RootTestModule a valid NestJS module?
    - If "UserRepository" is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If "UserRepository" is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing "UserRepository" */ ]
      })

       6 |
       7 |   beforeEach(async () => {
    >  8 |     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
         |                                   ^
       9 |       providers: [UsersService],
      10 |     }).compile();
      11 |

      at TestingInjector.lookupComponentInParentModules (../../node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:254:19)

FYI, the users.service.ts file :
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserInput } from './dto/create-user.input';
import { UpdateUserInput } from './dto/update-user.input';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  create(createUserInput: CreateUserInput) {
    return 'This action adds a new user';
  }

  findAll() {
    try {
      const users = this.userRepository.find();
      return users;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Unable to fetch users : ' + error.message);
    }
  }

  findOne(id: number) {
    return `This action returns a #${id} user`;
  }

  update(id: number, updateUserInput: UpdateUserInput) {
    return `This action updates a #${id} user`;
  }

  remove(id: number) {
    return `This action removes a #${id} user`;
  }
}

It seems I need to import the UserRepository, implemented in users.service.ts, in the RootTestModule, but I couldn't find this file. I suppose it's set in the configuration of UserModule but I'm out of ideas.
Thanks in advance !
